# Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp: address https://60.248.172.3:8545: too many colons in address

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, web3-providers

I need to connect geth rpc using `https://60.248.172.3` in web3.js because my website is running in secure mode(https://example.com)
I tried this and got error:

`geth --rpc --rpcaddr "https://60.248.172.3"`

> Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp: address
>   https://60.248.172.3:8545: too many colons in address

How can I add https:// in start of my ip(60.248.172.3) using --rpcaddr?

The main issue is chrome browser can't allow web3.js to send ajax post request to http://60.248.172.3:8545 when my site is opened with https://example.com(https)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `--rpcaddr 60.248.172.3` and `--rpcport 443`.

But as far as I know `geth` does not support SSL protocol. You can set up an Nginx reverse proxy to handle such case.

Comment: what is difference b/w 8545 and 443?

Comment: These are different ports. 443 is usually used for SSL connection. 8545 for RPC interface connection. You can configure your web server to use SSL on 8545 port also if you need.

Comment: can you please provide some example for : ` Nginx reverse proxy to handle such case`

Comment: Check the [related topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/768509/lets-encrypt-with-an-nginx-reverse-proxy?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)